# Grabbing certain parts of a RowDataPacket

Tags: javascript, node.js

so im using this code: 
`` con.query(`select max(ticketid) from tickets`, (err, rows) => {
console.log(err)
console.log(rows[0])
}) `` 

Current Output: `RowDataPacket { 'max(ticketid)': 1 }` 
Expected Output: `1`

I tried a solution which is `JSON.stringify`, and i got an output `[{"max(ticketid)":1}]` which isnt much different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `rows[0]['max(ticketid)']`